# Add foreign keys relationship to Entity Framework Database first

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, mapping, asp.net-3.5, one-to-many

I have a database in **TSQL** and I use **ADO.NET Entity Framework from .NET 3.5** to create the matching entities.

In the database the relationships are not modeled, but in each table involved in a relationship there is a field representing the **foreign key** to another table's primary key.

For instance (assume a `Product` can have just one category):

```
Product ( ProdId(PK), ProdName, CatId(FK))

Category (CatId(PK), CatName)
```

This way of course there is **no referential integrity** constraint.

In my application I generate the EF entities from the database and then I add the relationships and their mapping by hand. Everything goes smooth except for the **one-to-many** relationships.

The mapping specified for the **many-to-many** relationships (through association table) do not give any kind of error, those specified for the **one-to-many**

> Error 3007: Problem in mapping fragments :Column(s) [foreign_key] are
>   being mapped in both fragments to different conceptual side
>   properties.

Now I checked the **mapping**, I changed **cardinality** and **directions** but still it does not work.

I read in the internet that I should remove the foreign keys but then, how can I map the values in the database? Is there any other solution?

Important: I cannot use .NET 4.0 I have to stuck with .NET 3.5

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369656/getting-error-3007-when-i-add-my-entity-model

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate, in my case the FK is also present in the database and I cannot remove it from my EF entities